# GROUP BY date range date

Tags: sql

I have a large table (about 15 million rows) of a hierarchy for work.
The current Hierarchy lists has 1 entry for every day, spanning about 2 years.

I am trying to combine these entries to capture any column change other than the date, and compile into 1 entry.

I have included an example of what my table would look like in Table1. and what I would like it to look like in Table2.

Also, these tables are simplistic versions, there are about 20 columns, and I would like to create an entry every time anything from any of the columns changes.

I can get about as far as doing a GROUP BY or a DISTINCT on the entire table, other than the Dates to get the records - but cant figure out how to attach the min and max dates of those distinct records?

I am currently using SSMS v18.0

TIA.

Table1

```
+------------+---------+-------+------------+
|    Date    |  Name   |  ID   | Supervisor |
+------------+---------+-------+------------+
| 2020-01-01 | Chad    | 12345 | John       |
| 2020-01-02 | Chad    | 12345 | John       |
| 2020-01-03 | Chad    | 12345 | John       |
| 2020-01-04 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-05 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-06 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-07 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-08 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-09 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-10 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-01 | Patrick | 54321 | John       |
| 2020-01-02 | Patrick | 54321 | John       |
| 2020-01-03 | Patrick | 54321 | John       |
| 2020-01-04 | Patrick | 54321 | John       |
| 2020-01-05 | Patrick | 54321 | John       |
| 2020-01-06 | Patrick | 54321 | John       |
| 2020-01-07 | Patrick | 54321 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-08 | Patrick | 54321 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-09 | Patrick | 54321 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-10 | Patrick | 54321 | Stephen    |
+------------+---------+-------+------------+
```

Table 2

```
+------------+------------+---------+-------+------------+
| StartDate  |  EndDate   |  Name   |  ID   | Supervisor |
+------------+------------+---------+-------+------------+
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 | Chad    | 12345 | John       |
| 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-10 | Chad    | 12345 | Stephen    |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-06 | Patrick | 54321 | John       |
| 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-10 | Patrick | 54321 | Stephen    |
+------------+------------+---------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Images of your tables are not useful. Please provide the information in text form. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem. See [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). When making the [edit] to do so, please also add your effort to solve the problem yourself and a tag for the specific DBMS you're using. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you addressed about half of what I asked. Can you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using and the SQL you've written trying to solve the problem yourself now?

Comment: @KenWhite I would highly recommend you adjust your approach to responses. They are very abrasive. Obviously based on the stats of my profile - I am new to posting here. Yet, 2 people were able to respond with the answer and resolution in the time it took me to figure out "half of what you asked". Whereas I am very appreciative of people on forums, and try to abide by the proper etiquette - there are definitely better ways to handle your approach and response.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you learn to accept constructive advice that is trying to both get you a quicker answer on this question AND to improve your future experiences here by helping you learn how the site works. You're welcome, BTW. If you're so thin-skinned that someone asking you for additinoal information hurts your feelings or offends you, a site like SO may not be the best fit for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select person, id_number, supervisor, min(date), max(date)
from (select h.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by person, id_number, supervisor order by date) as seqnum_2
      from hierarchy h
     ) h
group by (seqnum - seqnum_2), person, id_number, supervisor
```

Comment: Much appreciated - this is perfect! Now to apply to the entire table and see processing time :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the LAG windowing function.

```
Oracle: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions#lag
SQLite: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-lag/
```

Like so:

```sql
select *
from (
  select 
    t.date start_date,  
    lag(date, 1) end_date,
    person,
    id_number,
    supervisor,
    case when
      decode(person, lag(person, 1), 1, 0) = 1 or
      decode(supervisor, lag(supervisor, 1), 1, 0) = 1 or
      decode(column_to_check_1, lag(column_to_check_1, 1), 1, 0) = 1 or
      decode(column_to_check_2, lag(column_to_check_2, 1), 1, 0) = 1
    then 1 else 0 end change_detect
  from (
    select * 
    from table1 
    order by person, date) t
  )
where change_detect = 1
order by date, person;
```